# Selenium - waiting until element disappears last long

Tags: c#, selenium

I am looking for better solution to wait until element disappear. Now I am using:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
    wait.Until((ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(element)));
```

This method is working, but it last long. Element is invisible in dom after ~2sec but driver is waiting for this condition <20 sec. I was looking for another solutions, but couldn't find one which will work in .net. 
I am using IE to run my tests.

Comment: try setting `wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);` at second line and see.

Comment: wait.Timeout is not the same as timeout in WebDriverWait?

Comment: `WebDriverWait` is the object type. You have to assign a timeout to the object- `wait`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume that you're mixing implicit and explicit waits, which causes collision. You should make sure that implicit waits are set to 0 in case of using `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I don't have implicit waits in this application at all, but I reduced amount of explicit wait. Now It takes about ~10 second to finish this line :ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(@by);

Comment: @KamilLeśniak that's weird, as `WebDriverWait` polling should be interrupted immediately when specified condition is met. And from your description / comment it seems like you're waiting for max specified amount of time, but not getting timeout exception. Which driver / IE versions are you using?

Comment: For me it is also weird, I  have to wait for this element on few page objects. I am using IE driver server 3.4.0 32bit and IE 11